# Installing TinyOS 1.x and TOSSIM in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless, sensors, tinyos, nesc

I've been into a project for evaluating the performance of a wireless sensor network. I need to work with TinyOS 1.x  and nesC. Also I need to install TOSSIM simulator. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently went through this myself. There's a lot of different installation instructions for TinyOS 1.x, and many of them are out of date or run into issues--source packages needing patches, etc.

This is the guide I found that worked:
[GEMS TinyOS 1.x Ubuntu Guide](http://leme.tagus.ist.utl.pt/gems/PmWiki/index.php/resources/HowToInstallTinyOS)

Of course, the TinyOS 1.x CVS has been taken down, I think, so instead of grabbing CVS source, take the latest tarball (1.1.15) from here:
[TinyOS 1.x Source Distribution](http://webs.cs.berkeley.edu/tos/dist-1.1.0/tinyos/source/?C=M;O=D)

Good luck!

P.S. If those don't work, there's the XubunTOS vmware image, which is built for TOS2.x, but still has most of the TOS1.x system in place and available.
[XubunTOS VMWare Image](http://docs.tinyos.net/index.php/Running_a_XubunTOS_Virtual_Machine_Image_in_VMware_Player)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed tinyos-2.x and made a presentation.
Here is the link:

http://www.slideshare.net/prakhar21/intoduction-to-tinyos-nesc-and-tossim

If you have any problem regarding installing you can ask, I'll try.